# Jquery get css attribute top not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I am trying to get top and left attributes from element on page with jquery but it's not working.

Can you tell me how it's possible?

Thanks for any response

HTML code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 370px; top: 0px;">
    <img class="name" src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.name', function(){
    top = $(this).parent().css('top');
    left = $(this).parent().css('left');
    alert("Top: " + top + ",Left: " + left);
});
```

JQuery response:

```
Top: [object Window],Left: 185px
```

Comment: Remember, `window` also has a `top` property :) A good reminder that you should use *descriptive* variable names and avoid global variables

Comment: Read http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
top = $(this).parent().css('top');
```

This is pulling back the readonly `window.top` property which cannot be assigned to. Either scope the `top` variable, or give it a more relevant name:

```
$('body').on('click', '.name', function(){
    var top = $(this).parent().css('top');
    var left = $(this).parent().css('left');
    alert("Top: " + top + ",Left: " + left);
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6eQE/)